# Creating own malloc for an assignment. Getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc, nodes

The segmentation fault occurs at the point with the comment. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm not initializing the head and tail Nodes. I've tried to initialize the to NULL as well and that didn't work. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to initialize them without using malloc. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//the structure of the node in the linked list
typedef struct Node{
    int size;
    int status;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* previous;
}Node;

int* HEAP_START = 0;
int* HEAP_END = 0;
Node* head;
Node* tail;

int first = 0;
//printf("here1\n");

void *my_bestfit_malloc(int size)
{
    Node* newNode = NULL;
    printf("here2\n");
    if(first == 0)
    {
        HEAP_START = (int*)sbrk(0);
        newNode = sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
        HEAP_END = (int*)sbrk(0);
        head->next = tail;      //segmentation error happens here
        printf("here3\n");
        tail->previous = head;
        newNode->size = size;
        newNode->status = 1;
        first++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* currNode = head->next;
        printf("here4\n");
        while(currNode->next != tail)
        {
            if(currNode->size == size)
            {
                newNode = currNode;
                currNode->previous->next = currNode->next;
                currNode->next->previous = currNode->previous;
                newNode->size = size;
                newNode->status = 1;
                printf("here5\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                currNode = currNode->next;
                printf("here6\n");
            }
        }
        if(currNode->next == tail)
        {
            newNode = sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
            HEAP_END = (int*)sbrk(0);
            newNode->size = size;
            newNode->status = 1;
            printf("here7\n");
        }
    }
    return newNode + sizeof(Node);
}

 int main()
{
    typedef struct person{
        int age;
        char sex;
    }person;
    printf("main1\n");
    person* dave = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));
    printf("main2\n");
    person* vicki = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));
    printf("main3");
    person* alex = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));

    dave->age = 26;
    dave->sex = 'M';

    vicki->age = 24;
    vicki->sex = 'F';

    alex->age = 19;
    alex->sex = 'F';

    printf("Dave:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
    printf("Vicki:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
    printf("Alex:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
}
```

So I tried changing my Node* head and tail to: Node head; Node tail; instead, but received these errors:

```
mymalloc.c: In function ‘my_bestfit_malloc’:
mymalloc.c:38: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:40: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:47: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:49: error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘struct Node *’     and ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:67: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘struct Node *’     and ‘Node’)
```

I understand the first three, I need to use head.next = tail; instead, but I don't understand the last two.

Final edit:
Got if figured out. The pointers for head and tail need to be actual Node structs instead of struct pointers. Also I needed to return a void pointer instead of a Node.

Comment: Have you tried tracing through all the pointers to make sure they are pointing to where you think they should be with a debugger?

Comment: You didn't assign to head: where should it point to? What environment are you writing in? Malloc is normally implemented by the OS.

Comment: If you create a pointer to it, you're responsible for allocating memory with malloc. If you create a 'normal' variable (not a pointer), the compiler allocate space for it on the stack. So use "Node head, tail;" instead of "Node *head, *tail;".

Comment: Did you get it  figured out?

Comment: @Chimera: Yes! Sorry I forgot to post, was finishing it up. The problem was that the Nodes for head and tail needed to be Node objects not Node pointers. Also, I needed to return a void pointer, not a Node.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning values to head. head hasn't been allocated.

change:

```
Node* head;
Node* tail;
```

to:

```
Node head;
Node tail;
```

And when accessing a member of pointer to a `struct use ->`. Such as `head->size`
And when accessing a member of a `struct use .` Such as `head.size`.

I made some changes to your code and now the program at least can allocate the and use the first `person`. However subsequent allocations of type `person` fails. I suspect perhaps `void *my_bestfit_malloc(int size)` has some logic/pointer issues....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//the structure of the node in the linked list
typedef struct Node{
    int size;
    int status;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* previous;
}Node;

int* HEAP_START = 0;
int* HEAP_END = 0;
struct Node head;
struct Node tail;

int first = 0;
//printf("here1\n");

void *my_bestfit_malloc(int size)
{
    Node* newNode = NULL;
    printf("here2\n");
    if(first == 0)
    {
        HEAP_START = (int*)sbrk(0);
        newNode = sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
        HEAP_END = (int*)sbrk(0);
        head.next = &tail;      //segmentation error happens here
        printf("here3\n");
        tail.previous = &head;
        newNode->size = size;
        newNode->status = 1;
        first++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* currNode = head.next;
        printf("here4\n");
        while( currNode != &tail)
        {
            if(currNode->size == size)
            {
                newNode = currNode;
                currNode->previous->next = currNode->next;
                currNode->next->previous = currNode->previous;
                newNode->size = size;
                newNode->status = 1;
                printf("here5\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                currNode = currNode->next;
                printf("here6\n");
            }
        }
        if(currNode->next == &tail)
        {
            newNode = sbrk(size + sizeof(Node));
            HEAP_END = (int*)sbrk(0);
            newNode->size = size;
            newNode->status = 1;
            printf("here7\n");
        }
    }
    return newNode + sizeof(Node);
}

 int main()
{
    typedef struct person{
        int age;
        char sex;
    }person;
    printf("main1\n");
    person* dave = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));
    printf("main2\n");
    person* vicki = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));
    printf("main3");
    person* alex = (person*)my_bestfit_malloc(sizeof(person));

    dave->age = 26;
    dave->sex = 'M';

    //vicki->age = 24;
    //vicki->sex = 'F';

    //alex->age = 19;
    //alex->sex = 'F';

    printf("Dave:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
    //printf("Vicki:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
    //printf("Alex:\n\tAge: %d\n\tSex: %c\n", dave->age, dave->sex);
}
```

Running the code now it least gives the following output:

```
jrn@VirtualBox-mint17 ~ $ ./a.out 
main1
here2
here3
main2
here2
here4
main3here2
here4
Dave:
    Age: 26
    Sex: M
```

Comment: Did that originally, but then I get these errors:


mymalloc.c: In function ‘my_bestfit_malloc’:

mymalloc.c:38: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)

mymalloc.c:40: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)

mymalloc.c:47: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:49: error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘struct Node *’ and ‘Node’)
mymalloc.c:67: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘struct Node *’ and ‘Node’)

Comment: @user292277 Use a dot to access members of structs. -> is used to access members of pointers. So use head.size instead of head->size

Comment: It would cleaner to intialize a Node* head to NULL and to NULL check at insertion