# Linked Lists not working correctly when implementing malloc

Tags: c

I'm trying to create my own version of malloc using best fit.  To do this I am using linked lists to keep track of the allocations.  However when I go to allocate space, the linked lists dont seem to be connecting.  I've gone through the code over and over but can't see the problem.  Any help would be appreciated so much.

Comment: Is this the same assignment as in [**Creating own malloc for an assignment. Getting a segmentation fault**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187873/creating-own-malloc-for-an-assignment-getting-a-segmentation-fault) If so, you need to clearly state that this is for a homework assignment to help prevent numerous similar questions scattered across across the list.

Comment: That wasn't mine but it looks similar.  This is for a project.

Comment: post the contents of `#include "mymalloc.h"`. So the struct/list definition is available.

Comment: Header file is up.  Sorry was having some trouble with Internet connection...

Comment: What does the source for `my_free()` look like? I assume that is the function that puts memory areas onto the free list?

Comment: Will take a look. Also, just a tip, for all **positive** counters, indexes, etc, use `size_t` instead of `int` since the values will not be negative (or should be an error if they are...).

Comment: I haven't done my free yet because I was trying to get this section finished first.  I am not able to simply malloc multiple times in a row without getting the error so it should't have to do with free.  Thanks for the tip about counters but not sure where they are in my code...

Comment: What problem are you having? I just used your code, e.g. `char *str = my_bestfit_malloc (STRSZ * sizeof *str);` allocated space, printed the string, checked the pointer address -- and got no errors??

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to malloc 3 or more times in a row.   I will post a longer test code in the main question that tries to malloc a tree.

Comment: I posted the code at the bottom of the question for a very simple test.  The test works the first two times but then has a segmentation error on the third time.  I believe the segmentation error occurs in  my_bestfit_malloc inside of the while loop...

Comment: If found the issue on subsequent allocations. looking.

Comment: He did, your segfault occurred here `if (current->used == 0 && current->mallocsize > size)`, I found the segfault: e.g. `0x0000000000400763 in my_bestfit_malloc (size=128) at malloc_sbrk_ll.c:51` and then saw that an answer was already posted. `gdb` is your friend here. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @DanSmith. You will want a more rigorous test than your sample. Try declaring/filling an array of pointers to `char *`. e.g. `#define MAXS 256` ... `char **str = my_bestfit_malloc (MAXS * sizeof *str);` ... then fill with e.g. `str[idx] = my_bestfit_malloc (MAXS * sizeof **str);` up to `idx < MAXS`. Just to make sure you have exercised all aspects of your code.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is in allocating your node structures:

```
root = (struct node *)sbrk(sizeof(root));
...
added = (struct node *)sbrk(sizeof(root));
```

Should be:

```
root = (struct node *)sbrk(sizeof(*root));
...
added = (struct node *)sbrk(sizeof(*root));
```

At best, your nodes and your allocations would "share" memory incorrectly.

Also, I think you need to be careful to ensure proper alignment of your memory.  I'm not sure your code (or `sbrk`) does that.

Here's a problem with your splitting code:

```
return best+sizeof(best);
...
newnode = best+best->mallocsize+sizeof(root);
```

Since `best` is a `struct node*`, these additions jump further ahead in memory than I think you intended.  I think you meant to cast `best` to a `(char*)` in these expressions.

Also, I think the computation for `newnode` is wrong, even after you cast to `(char*)`.  I think you want something more like:

```
newnode = best + 1 + size / sizeof(*root) + !!(size % sizeof(*root));
```

You also forget to compute and set `newnode->mallocsize`!

The following math probably will be done in unsigned (i.e. - `int`'s promoted to `size_t`'s):

```
if (best->mallocsize-size-sizeof(short) < sizeof(root)) {
```

In that case, you can underflow 0 on the left hand side, which will cause you to improperly split the node.  You can fix this by throwing the subtraction over to the other side of the inequality because you already ensured that `size < best->mallocsize`:

```
if (best->mallocsize - size < sizeof(root) + sizeof(short)) {
```

Couple of other points:

- In your best fit search, you almost always skip over the root for some reason.
- In your best fit search, you don't consider unused node's whose `mallocsize` equals `size`.
- In your best fit search, once you find an optimally sized unused node (i.e. - `size == current->mallocsize`), end the search (i.e. - break the loop).
- **In your allocations you call `sbrk` twice: once for your node and once for the application's memory.  If you are doing this to ensure proper alignment of memory, then that's good (assuming `sbrk` does this for you), but then your assumption that a `node + 1` gives you the address of the application's memory may not be true.**

Comment: YES!  That worked.  Thank you I can't believe I just spent 5 hours of my life on an asterisk....

Comment: You have the same problem in your later allocation too.  I'll edit.

Comment: @DanSmith Found some more issues.

Comment: Thanks man, I think I got them all fixed.  I moved the current=current->next to after the if statement.  I added a >= to the if statement and a break.  For the last part I did change it.  I though my way would be simpler I guess I didn't take into account the sbrk doing alignment. I allocated the whole thing in the first sbrk and then that pointer plus the node size at the end.